# Latest raw version of a file on GitHub

Tags: github

On GitHub there is a **raw** button that allows you to download the raw contents of a file.
The raw URL is for that particular version of the file.

Is it possible to get a raw URL that always downloads the latest version of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to specify a branch name instead of an object ID in the URL.  For example, to always get the version of Git's README that's on the `master` branch, you can use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/README.md.

However, be aware that, like all accesses to `raw.githubusercontent.com`, there is caching involved and that can't be disabled, so while the URL will eventually be updated, it may not be immediately.  If you need the absolute latest version of a file at all times, or if you need that file for an automated process (such as another website or a program), then you need to host it yourself.